# KIF Test Case Crash at UIView-KIFAdditions.m class iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xctest, kif-framework

I want to write UI automation testing for one of my projects. I have did the following steps to setup the environment,

1.Create a new project (KIFDemo) with “Include Unit Tests” and “Include UI Tests”.
2.Created a Login page with “Username, Password TextFields and Login button”. Added Accessibility Label values.
3.Added KIF through Cocoa Pod like this,

> target 'KIFDemo' do
>
> ## Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
>
> ## use_frameworks!
>
> ## Pods for KIFDemo
>
> target 'KIFDemoTests' do inherit! :search_paths
>
> ## Pods for testing pod 'KIF', '~> 3.2.0' pod 'Specta', '~> 1.0.2' end
>
> target 'KIFDemoUITests' do inherit! :search_paths
>
> ## Pods for testing
>
> end
>
> end

4.Created one UITests.m (SubClass of KIFTestCase) under “KIFDemoTests” folder.
I have added this “beforeAll” function and code,

> - (void) beforeAll {
>
> [tester enterText:@"user@example.com"
>   intoViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"UsernameTF"]; [tester
>   enterText:@"thisismypassword"
>   intoViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"PasswordTF"];
>
> [tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"LoginButton"]; }

When I try to test this, am getting crash on following line,

> // Handle touches in the normal way for other views UITouch *touch =
>   [[UITouch alloc] initAtPoint:point inView:self]; [touch
>   setPhaseAndUpdateTimestamp:UITouchPhaseBegan];
>
> UIEvent *event = [self eventWithTouch:touch];
>
> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendEvent:event];// Getting Thread
>   1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Can anyone please help me to fix this and test the app? I don't know what is breaking this one. Looking forward help. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Yuvaraj M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is the bug in `KIF-framework`, you can see this in various discussion on [here1](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/issues/562),[here2](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/pull/581) and finally [here](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/pull/582)

Comment: hope you are doing good. And thanks for the response. So, my KIF setup is correct isn't? Thanks.

Comment: yes 100 % , the problem in UIKit evnt with touch problem on kif site

Comment: Thank you. I will let you know once I fixed this or if I struck somewhere. Thanks again.

Comment: @Yuvaraj.M - sure and have a happy day